# Direct Product of Rings and isomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, direct-product

Is there a way of finding all possible isomorphisms on the direct product of rings? I know that if the rings are of different size, direct product isomorphism induces automorphism on each rings, and if the rings are the same (isomorphically), then it also induces isomorphism in between the structures in addition to the automorphisms, but are these the only possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general not, it highly depends on what your rings in the product are. But you can reformulate the question in light of catogory theory: by universal property of products  endomorphisms $\phi: A \times B \to A \times B$ are 1-1 to pairs $(\phi_A:A \times B \to A, \phi_B:A \times B \to B)$. Sometimes it helps when you have more informations about $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Lets say we have taken product of finite field Fp^2 three times. Can you say what will be the automorphisms?

Comment: I cannot give you a concrete answer but this approach I sketched above allows to do some exclusions. eg a ring endomorphism $\phi$ on $(Fp^2)^3$ cannot be a isomorphism if one of the morphisms $(Fp^2)^3 \to Fp^2$ of the corresponding triple to $\phi$ isn't surjective (why? That's pure set theory) As I proposed we can instead study triples of ring morphisms $(Fp^2)^3 \to Fp^2$. Which ring morphisms $(Fp^2)^3 \to Fp^2$ do you know?